# Extract text from an image of stacked record/book spines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to capture the text from a photograph of a shelf of vinyl record spines - for example [image: this image]. I want the end result to be an array of text strings where each represents a record from the image.

As you can see, the image contains a lot of text running top to bottom, of varying color, quality, and distortion.

I've been experimenting with using Cloud Vision to pull out the text:

```
        # Perform document text detection using Google Cloud Vision API
        response = client.document_text_detection(image=image_data)
        document = response.full_text_annotation
```

I get mixed results, with some text being picked up, other text not so much.

The challenge is that the snippets of half-baked titles gets mixed in with fully transcribed titles, so it's hard to reliably parse the results.

I've been experimenting with using cv2 adaptive thresholding to try and distinguish between each item more clearly - for example:

```
# Load the image
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Apply adaptive thresholding to enhance text contrast
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

# Save the thresholded image
thresholded_image_path = 'thresholded.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(thresholded_image_path, thresh)
```

This yields [image: a somewhat clearer result] (at least to my eye) but I don't get much further with the extraction of text.

Does anyone have any ideas for making this work? Perhaps slicing into individual images based on the thresholding would be worth trying?

Comment: fundamentally an OCR task. you should let the OCR handle the processing. avoid OCR that requires preprocessing. any manual processing will only degrade the picture. it will be counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Christoph Rackwitz, it is fundamentally an OCR task. Any manual processing will only degrade the picture and avoid OCR that requires preprocessing.

Try this request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI2vY.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki and feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.